# Convert Lead button working in Lightning and Sandbox but not Classic

Tags: lightning, lead-conversion, convert, classic, findduplicates

The Convert Lead button has suddenly stopped working in Classic. The button is on the lead page but when clicked nothing happens. No changes have been made to permissions and I've rechecked them all. If I change to Lightning the Convert Button works. And it works in the Sandbox for Classic.

There are no error messages.

I've been working on this instance of Salesforce for a couple of months and never had this problem. It only became a problem today.

UPDATE: The Find Duplicate button has stopped working as well. Nothing happens when I click on it.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check the "Developer Console" in your browser? There should be something somewhere if it's not working.

Comment: Try deleting your browser cache, cookies. It seems the problems occurs after spring 19 rolls out.

Comment: I deleted cookies and the browser cache but it didn't fix the problem. My production is on Spring 19 and my Sandbox is on Winter 19. As the Convert button works in the Sandbox it has to be an issue with Spring 19.

Comment: I had two other users on the same instance of Salesforce try to convert leads and it works for them. It must be an issue with my browser.

Comment: I have the same issue.  Worked fine but yesterday multiple standard users reported the same thing - have not updated the lead object or any permissions.

Comment: megaSteve4 - have you found a way to resolve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue with the Spring 19 roll out.  For us the convert lead button just failed and did nothing when clicked but other people have reported the same for other buttons too.  The chrome console was reporting an error on button click.

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000E10EQAS

As other users have suggested purging cached files in Chrome at least got all buttons working again for us.